# Find Fourier series $f(t) = e^{jx t}$ , $−\pi < t < \pi$

Tags: wavelet, fourier-series

I need to find the Fourier series of the $f(t) = e^{jxt}$ ,  $− \pi < t < \pi$
What will be the first step to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to find Fourier series just compare with equation $x(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}C_n*e^{j*w_n*t}$ we will know $C_n,w_n.$